# PHP & Base 2. Which Floats give a precise Value?

Tags: php, floating-point

Apologies for my poor maths skills, I've tried to understand this to answer my own query but I'm not convinced.

We all know that PHP doesn't store Floats in base 10 but base 2.

I have a series of calculations that are using 0.5 as the only float, and in trying to understand if they will be stored as 0.500001 or 0.4999999 (for rounding purposes there is a big difference!!!) I have come to understand that 0.5 will be stored precisely in base2.

My queries are

A Have I understood this correctly?

B What other floats are stored precisely in base2? eg 0.25?

Comment: means you have to store like  0.4999999  in your database ?

Comment: @liyakat, it's not related to my database, it's about php storing the variables

Comment: any multiple of 1/2 can be accurately represented. so .25 is good because it is a half of a half.

Comment: [gmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) is a good library for higher presision numbers

Comment: @orangepill, thanks, put that in the answers and i'll accept, also if you could expand and say if n/8, n/16 etc would give a precise float?

Comment: Whatever you do, if that degree of precision is required I strongly advise you to write test functions - run a series of values through your functions and test that they always produce the expected output.

Comment: @Robert, are you saying that (0.5 + 0.5 != 1) is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any multiple of 1/pow(x, 2) can be precisely represented as a float.

That means x/2, x/4, x/8, x/16 ...ect. can be accurately represented.

For more information on how floating point numbers are store see http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm

[Gmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) is a good library for high precision math.

Comment: Thanks! Lovely link too!! I see myself always advocating such fractions in all projects!! Ha ha... pricing such as $12.625 seems very reasonable to me!

Comment: I think "Any integer multiple of a power of 2" would be a bit more accurate. 1/8 is representable, 1/10 is not. What is the difference? Either both are multiples of 1/2 or neither is, depending on how you define "multiple".

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not required to use binary floating-point. [It depends on the system.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Many systems use IEEE-754 binary floating-point (sometimes incompletely or with modifications, such as flushing subnormal numbers to zero).

In IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating point, a number is exactly representable if and only if it is representable as an integer *F* times a power of two, 2<sup>*E*</sup>, such that:

- The magnitude of *F* is less than 2<sup>53</sup>.
- –1074 ≤ *E* < 972.

For example, ½ equals 1•2<sup>–1</sup>. 1 is an integer under the integer limit, and –1 is an exponent within the exponent limits. So ½ is representable.

2<sup>53</sup>+1 is not representable. As it is, it is an integer outside the integer limit. If you try to scale it by a power of two to bring it within the limit, you get a number that is not an integer. So there is no way to represent this value exactly in IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point.

1/3 and 1/10 are also not representable because no matter what power of two you scale them by, you will not produce an integer.